# Discord.js integration role to bot

Tags: discord.js

Hi everyone i am trying to code my own bot but i don't know to set these auto intergrated roles like this one,can someone explain me how they did this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTWv5.png)

Answer (score 1):

Bots automatically create their own role with customised permissions(in the invite), the role cannot be added to other users.

Answer (score 0):

When I add a `bot` to my server, a `role` is **automatically created** that is named like the bot.

I don't know if the message in the screenshot is exactly from this, but I can't add `members` to this `bot role` or edit it, only the bot has it and can have it.